# Can we host Azure PaaS services on AKS

Tags: azure, azure-aks, paas

We are currently using Azure PaaS services like Azure Data Factory, Azure Databricks, Azure Storage Account, Azure Synapse Analytics, Power BI.
Is it possible to run these PaaS services on container service - Azure Kubernetes Service[AKS] so that entire data pipeline can run as containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you want an entirely containerized solution, you'll need to find or build containerized alternatives to these Azure services.